# Creating Data Tables for Machine Learning in Swift using CreateML

Tags: swift, machine-learning, createml

Apple has recently released a framework that allows to create machine learning models. I am interested in [tabular data](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/createml/creating_data_tables_for_training_and_evaluation) but I haven't found any example online. Could anyone please provide a piece of code that works? I have tried the following provided by Apple without success:

```
import CreateML

// Specify Data
let trainingCSV = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/createml/HouseData.csv")
let houseData = MLDataTable(contentsOf: trainingCSV)
let (trainingData,testData) = houseData.randomSplit(by: 0.8, seed: 0)

// Create Model
let pricer = try MLRegressor(trainingData: houseData, targetColumn: "price")

// Evaluate Model
let metrics = try pricer.testingMetrics(on: testData)

// Save Model
try pricer.write(to: URL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/createml/HousePricer.mlmodel"))
```

In particular this code throws me the following error on line 4 and 15:

> error: MyPlaygroundu.playground:9:22: error: use of unresolved identifier 'URL'
>   try pricer.write(to: URL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/createml/HousePricer.mlmodel"))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`URL` is from the `Foundation` framework.

Add:

```
import Foundation
```

just before `import CreateML`.

Comment: That's another issue for another question. Mark this one as resolved. Then do some research into your new errors. If needed, post a new question with all relevant details.